# WebSocket closes immediately after opening/send

Tags: python, websocket

I'm making a simple chat using `websockets` on client and `flask` + `flask_sockets` on server.

When the client gets their token, connects to a websocket and sends a message, `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed` appears

Client code:

```py
async def main(token):
    async with websockets.connect(f'ws://localhost:5000/ws?token={token}') as ws:
        await ws.send(input('> '))
        print(await ws.recv())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = input('Your username >>> ').strip()
    token = get(f'http://localhost:5000/getToken?username={username}').text
    print(f"Got token: {token}")

    while True:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(token))
```

Server WebSocket handler:

```py
class User:
    ws = None

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username


@sockets.route('/ws')
def alert(ws):
    token = request.args.get('token')
    if token in users:
        user = users[token]
        user.ws = ws
        print(f'Connected user {token}')
    print(users[token].username, '>>>', ws.receive())
```

I expect the connection to stay open so when a new message appears server would send it to all clients using something like

```py
for user in users:
    user.ws.send(message)
```

P.S. this is my first post on StackOverflow, so any corrections are welcome :)

Comment: Apparently, removing `print(await ws.recv())` solves this issue, but i couldn't find any information on event listeners in `websockets`

Comment: So, how did you receive the server responses on the client if you removed the ws.recv()?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the same problem, the answer is to use a for loop to continually read in messages as described in the docs [here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/patterns.html#consumer).

Adjusted for the question:

```py
async def main(token):
    async with websockets.connect(f'ws://localhost:5000/ws?token={token}') as ws:
        async for message in ws:
            # note: message can be a string or bytes
            print(message)
...
```